# AWK search a file from list in another file and format output

Tags: awk

I think this question has been answered before but I haven't been able to find one that addresses this specific need.

I am running into difficulties when using AWK to search a ~150mb text file of Ethernet packets for occurrences of a string from a list in csv (or text) file.  One of the issues seems to be the leading spaces in the data file as well as the information after the colon in the data file.

I want to search the data file for the term "Epoch" in $1.  That will be in every frame, then search for any of the terms in the list file that are found before the next occurrence of "Epoch" in $1 and if they are found print ($3/86400+25569)(to format it to work with Excel time format) from the "Epoch" line and then any of the occurrences from the list file separated by a comma(,).

The list file looks like this

```
bill_more_data:
and_more_data:
pay_hour:
age_years:
favorite_adventure_type:
```

The data file looks like this.

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination
      1 0.000000       xxx.xx.xxx.x           xxx.xx.xxx.x

Frame 1: 52 bytes on wire (100 bits), 22 bytes captured (757 bits)
    Arrival Time: Jun 28, 2021 04:17:23.747890000 Pacific Daylight Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1624879043.747890000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1
 Ethernet II, Src: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x), Dst: xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x)
    Destination: xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x)
        Address: xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x)
        .... .... .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... .... .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: xxx.xx.xxx.x, Dst: 000.00.00.00
    Flags: 0x0, Don't fragment
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
Info Header
    message_id: 000x00
    message_length: 2
bill_some_data
    bill_that_data: 0
    bill_more_data: 1
    and_more_data: 0

0000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................

No.     Time           Source                Destination        
      2 0.000275       xxx.xx.xxx.x          xxx.xx.xxx.x          

Frame 2: 60 bytes on wire (454 bits), 55 bytes captured (454 bits)

    Arrival Time: Jun 28, 2021 04:17:23.748165000 Pacific Daylight Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1624879043.748165000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000275000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 2
   Ethernet II, Src: xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x), Dst: xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x)
    Destination: xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x)
        Address: xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x (xxx:xxx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.28.1.72, Dst: 172.28.1.30
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Flags: 0x00
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment Offset: 0
    [Stream index: 1]
Info Header
    message_id: 0x00000
    message_length: 5
TED_name
    pay_hour: 3.25
    vacation_days: 0
    age_years: 22
    time_in_role: 0.1
    favorite_adventure_type: excellent
```

I have tried the following but I get no output.  If I change the list file to include the info after the colon then it will at least print those lines but that doesn't do me much good here.

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' list.txt data.txt`

Desired output

```
44375.4704137487,bill_more_data,1,bill_more_data,1
1624879043.748165000,pay_hour,3.25,age_years,22,favorite_adventure_type,excellent
```

or better with the epoch time formatted to work in Excel

```
44375.4704137487,bill_more_data,1,bill_more_data,1
44375.4704137518,pay_hour,3.25,age_years,22,favorite_adventure_type,excellent
```

I have tried several other methods with limited success. I am looking for a graceful way to do this that will also be able to handle future changes to the formatting in the way that these values are recorded. One of the other ways I tried was to run several AWK commands to first reverse the file, then search for the list items and print them, then search for the next occurrence or "Epoch" and print $3, then reverse the file again, then another AWK to printf any lines that aren't "Epoch".  That did seem to work okay if I entered the list items directly in the command itself but I couldn't get it to work if I was trying to read from another file.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.  This is my first dive into using AWK so please forgive me if I am asking a stupid question.

Comment: The fundamental problem with your attempt is that it examines one line at a time. You want to instead split the second file into multi-line records, then search within each record for your strings. I guess the first line in each record is the `No.     Time           Source     ` line so you would provide that as `RS`. (Spaces get compressed here in the comments but I'm sure you can guess what I'm looking at.)

Comment: Great first question - clear requirements, concise, testable sample input and expected output, and an attempt at solving the problem yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    tags[$0]
    next
}
$1 == "Epoch" {
    prt()
    time = $3
}
$1 in tags {
    tag2val[$1] = $2
}
END {
    prt()
}

function prt(   out) {
    if ( time != "" ) {
        out = sprintf("%0.10f",(time / 86400) + 25569)
        for (tag in tag2val) {
            val = tag2val[tag]
            sub(/:/,"",tag)
            out = out OFS tag OFS val
        }
        print out
    }
    delete tag2val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk list file
44375.4704137487,and_more_data,0,bill_more_data,1
44375.4704137519,favorite_adventure_type,excellent,age_years,22,pay_hour,3.25
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, 
That is an amazing bit of code.  I do run into an issue when FNR is over 20000.  it will start to print ever line that contains "Epoch" and nothing after that. Is the 20k lines a limitation of AWK with MAX_LONG?  I can't find much info on this. 
Is there a solution to this?  In a comment above Tripleee mentioned creating multi-line records of each frame.  The files I'm dealing with is about 19k frames so that might work but when I was experimenting with that it was much slower than your code.

Comment: @isaac - you're welcome. No, there is no such limit. If it's not printing lines that contain those other tags then they don't exist in the input (at least not in the same way they exist in the sample input you provided, e.g. maybe they aren't separated by spaces from the rest of the line, or maybe you're missing newlines or something). Look in your input file for a case where there's a tag you think should have its value printed but it doesn't and see what's different about that line vs others where it is printed.

Comment: To be clear though - the issue is with your input file, not the script or any limitations.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help me.  
It turned out there were two issues I was dealing with.  The first was that the sample file I posted had only 2 frames and both had the desired data but in reality many of the frames will not have any of the desired information so they need to be skipped.  I was able to overcome this with a few if statements and an incrementing variable.  Perhaps not the most graceful way to do it but it works well.

Comment: The other issue was file encoding. I was exporting the file as a test file from Wireshark in windows and copying it to my Windows Ubuntu terminal but that resulted in a file with **ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators** and that was causing issues with the alignment and creating new lines where they were not desired. I was able to overcome this using the dos2unix.  This is not the ideal solution because dos2unix is not standard so it requires instillation.  @Ed Morton, is there a way in the code to apply an RS to only one file?

Comment: `
BEGIN { OFS=","}
NR==FNR {
    tags[$0]
    next
}
$1 == "Epoch" {
    prt()
    time = $3
}
$1 in tags {
    tag2val[$1] = $2
}
END {
    prt()
}

function prt(   out) {
    if ( time != "" ) {
        out = sprintf("%0.10f",(time / 86400) + 25569)
        for (tag in tag2val) {
            val = tag2val[tag]
            sub(/:/,"",tag)
            out = out OFS tag OFS val
                        i = i + 1
       }
        if  (i !=x )
        {
        print out
        }
x = i
    }
    delete tag2val
}
`

Comment: @isaac just add `{ sub(/\r$/,"") }` as the first line of the script and it'll remove the CR at then end of the line.

Comment: if the content in data file contains content in the list file, how to change the command ```$1 in tags``` to meet the need? it didn't work if it change to ```$1~ tags[$0]```

Comment: @Jiao ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' list.txt data.txt`

This part is right:

```
NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}
```

that means at the end of `list.txt` the array `a` holds the strings in that file. But for the rest, you have to loop over that array to see what matches.  Something like:

```
/Epoch:/ {
    if( epoch ) { printf "\n" }
    epoch = 1
    printf "%s" $2
}
epoch != 1 { next }

for( term in a ) {
    if( $0 ~ term ) { printf ... }
}

END { if( epoch ) { print "\n" } }
```

That prints a new line after every epoch: before every one except the 1st one, and at the end if any were seen.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.  @Ed Morton, thank you for the help on this.  The script is working great!

It just needed a slight modification to filter out the blank time stamp line with an if statement and add { sub(/\r$/,"") } for the carriage return issue.

```
{ sub(/\r$/,"") }
BEGIN { OFS=","}
NR==FNR {
    tags[$0]
    next
}
$1 == "Epoch" {
    prt()
    time = $3
}
$1 in tags {
    tag2val[$1] = $2
}
END {
    prt()
}

function prt(   out) {
    if ( time != "" ) {
        out = sprintf("%0.10f",(time / 86400) + 25569)
        for (tag in tag2val) {
            val = tag2val[tag]
            sub(/:/,"",tag)
            out = out OFS tag OFS val
            i = i + 1
       }
    if  (i !=x )
    {
        print out
    }
x = i
    }
    delete tag2val
}
```